# Finding the primitive recursive characterstic function of a set

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, recursion, computability, formal-languages

**Context of the problem** I think it is important to say that this is how predicate quantification is defined in my textbook:

Let $\omega = \mathbb{N} + \{0\}$, $S_i \subseteq \omega, L_i \subseteq \Sigma^{*}$ for an arbitrary alphabet $\Sigma$. If

$$P : S_0 \times S_1 \times \ldots \times S_n \times L_1 \times \ldots \times L_m $$

is a predicate and $S \subseteq S_0$, then

$$(\forall t \in S)_{t \leq x}P(t, \overrightarrow{x}, \overrightarrow{\alpha})$$

is $1$ when $P(t, \overrightarrow{x}, \overrightarrow{\alpha}) = 1$ for all $t \leq x$. The domain of the quantified proposition is

$$\omega \times S_1 \times
\ldots \times S_n \times L_1 \times \ldots \times L_m $$

where the first argument (accounted by $\omega$) is the upper bound $x$. We accept without proof the following two statements, where "p.r." abbreviaties "primitive recursive":

> If $P: S_0 \times S_1 \times \ldots \times S_n \times L_1 \times\ldots \times L_m  \to \omega$ a predicate $\Sigma$-p.r., and $S \subseteq S_0$ is $\Sigma$-p.r., then both quantifications over $P$ are $\Sigma$-p.r.

> If $P: S_1 \times \ldots \times S_n \times L_1 \times \ldots \times L_m  L_{m+1} \to \omega$ a predicate $\Sigma$-p.r., and $L \subseteq L_{m+1}$ is $\Sigma$-p.r., then both quantifications over $P$ are $\Sigma$-p.r.

---

I was given the following problem.

> Let $\Sigma = \{@, !\}$. Show that $\{(2^x, @^x, !) : x \in \omega \land x \text{ is odd}\}$ is $\Sigma$-p.r. (this is, prove that it has a primitive recursive characteristic function).

Let $S$ denote the set in question. For clarity, observe that a few elements of
$S$ are

\begin{align*}
    (2, @, !), (8, @@@, !), (32, @@@@@, !), \ldots
\end{align*}

The set is $\Sigma$-p.r. if and only if there is a primitive recursive function
that determines whether a given tuple is in the set. It seems that, to determine
if a tuple in $\omega \times \Sigma^{*} \times \Sigma^{*}$ is in $S$, we should use
the function

\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{F} = \lambda xy \alpha \beta \left[ (\exists k \in \omega)_{k \leq
        x} \left( y = 2^{k+1} \land \alpha = @^{2k+1}\right) 
 \land \beta = !  \right] 
\end{align*}

However, at least in my textbook, the conjunction of two predicates $P_1 \land
P_2$ is defined only when the predicates have identical domains. However, the domain of $\lambda xy [x = 2^{y+ 1}]$ is $\omega^2$ and that of $\lambda x\alpha \left[ \alpha = @^{x+1}
\right] $ is $\omega \times \Sigma^{*}$. How could one define a valid, primitive
characteristic function of $S$?

Comment: Could you give the full citation of the source?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot, since it is the "textbook" written by my own professor in Spanish. It is not available anywhere outside my university.

Comment: Please let me know if there is some aspect in particular that needs more information